# How to set an invisible title on UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, title, alpha

I'm working on an Ipad application, and i need to set a title on a 'UIButton', in order to could use :

```
-(void)MyMethod:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    if ([resultButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"TitleName"])
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I use this sort of code :

```
[MyUibutton setTitle:@"TitleName" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It appears "TitleName" behind the image of the 'UIButton'...

So, is it possible to fix it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theButton.titleLabel.alpha = 0;`

Comment: This is not working all the time, but it inspire me this : button.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0f; which is working perfectly =)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the button title, it's for display, not a flag. Instead use a `tag` or `objc_setAssociatedObject` Or store the button in a dictionary and compare.

Comment: How could I use 'tag' as you mentionned in my case ?

Comment: Set the tag to a different value for each button and compare the tag instead of the name.

Comment: Theres an api "buttonIndexWithTitle:" for UIActionSheet, so its an over generalization to say its *just* for display. Obviously, its a valid way to retrieve the reference to a button in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image of the button, it will be at the top of the button, so the button's title won't be visible. Set the button's background and it will solve your problem !

```
[yourbutton setBackgroundImage:YOURIMAGE forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I want to put the image at the top, but it doesn't works because it transparent at parts

Answer (score 0):

You can do `[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateDisabled];` as long as you know you are not ever going to disable the button. Other than that, using the `tag` property is probably the easiest.